# Do failures seeking backwards in a gzip.GzipFile mean it's broken?

Tags: python, gzip, seek

I have files with a small header (8 bytes, say `zrxxxxxx`), followed by a gzipped stream of data. Reading such files works fine most of the time. However in very specific cases, seeking backwards fails. This is a simple way to reproduce:

```
from gzip import GzipFile

f = open('test.bin', 'rb')
f.read(8)  # Read zrxxxxxx

h = GzipFile(fileobj=f, mode='rb')
h.seek(8192)
h.seek(8191)  # gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'zr')
```

Unfortunately I cannot share my file, but it looks like *any* similar file will do.

Debugging the situation, I noticed that DecompressReader.seek (in Lib/_compression.py) sometimes rewinds the original *file*, which I suspect causes the issue:

```
#...
# Rewind the file to the beginning of the data stream.
def _rewind(self):
    self._fp.seek(0)
    #...

def seek(self, offset, whence=io.SEEK_SET):
    #...
    # Make it so that offset is the number of bytes to skip forward.
    if offset < self._pos:
        self._rewind()
    else:
        offset -= self._pos
    #...
```

Is this a bug? Or is it me doing it wrong?

Any simple workaround?

Comment: Streams usually aren't seekable. You can't seek backwards if you get a `gunzip -c <file.gz | yourprogram` pipeline, f/e. gzip _does_ support restart points where the compressor state is reset (basically, places inside the input stream where one just starts a completely new stream; gzip files can be concatenated together with the same effect as concatenating their contents), but you can only restart at those specific points.

Comment: That said, gzip streams that are built to be restarted at regular intervals are not all that common (one might look for tools with an option to create "rsyncable" gzip streams -- you'll notice that even in the limited set of tools that support it this option is almost always off-by-default because it trades against compression efficacy), so I wouldn't expect the Python standard library to go out of its way to support them (by doing things like rewinding back to the nearest restart point before the place one is trying to seek to, and then rolling forward from there).

Comment: I'm talking about a regular file here.

Comment: Right, but the output from opening a regular file with GzipFile is a stream of data; the file itself is a normal seekable file but its contents have to go through a stateful decompressor before they're usable, and that decompressor is running an algorithm that doesn't tolerate arbitrary seeking without extra work (like rewinding to an even-earlier point and restarting there) because the state it holds is specific to all the data it processed since the last restart point.

Comment: So you can't really seek in _either_ direction; to go forwards you need to decompress all the data even if you just throw it away, since if you don't decompress it you aren't updating the state table used for future decompression.

Comment: "Rewind to the very beginning and replay forward from there" is thus the safe-case way to do _any_ rewind, even a 1-byte rewind, because you need to get the compressor back into the state it was one byte ago.

Comment: I get the impression that GzipFile wants to support seeking regular files, even though it isn't fast. And I think it can, except that it should rewind the file to the starting position, *not* 0.

Comment: Usually (unless one is in a rsyncable/restarting stream of gzipped content, or a file that contains a gzip stream starting only after other non-gzipped content) "the starting position" _is_ 0, so for the general case it's a pretty reasonable assumption; it's how I would have written the library myself, if not explicitly given contrary requirements.

Comment: But yes -- if you want to use `tell()` to get the current offset when starting to operate, and then seek back to that point instead of to 0, I don't see why upstream wouldn't accept it as a patch (as long as it gracefully handled cases where those operations aren't possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Python. When you ask it to seek backwards, it has to go all the way back to the start of the gzip stream and start over. However the library did not take note of the offset of the file object it was given, so instead of rewinding to the start of the gzip stream, it is rewinding to the start of the file.

As for a workaround, you would need to give `GzipFile` a custom file object with a replaced `seek()` operation, such that `seek(0)` goes to the right place. This seemed to work:

```py
from gzip import GzipFile
f = open('test.bin', 'rb')
f.read(8)  # Read zrxxxxxx
class shift():
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.to = f.tell()
    def seek(self, offset):
        return self.f.seek(self.to + offset)
    def read(self, size=-1):
        return self.f.read(size)
s = shift(f)
h = GzipFile(fileobj=s, mode='rb')
h.seek(8192)
h.seek(8191)
```

(I don't really know Python, so I'm sure there's a better way. I tried to subclass `file` so that I would only need to intercept `seek()`, but somehow `file` is not actually a class.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my idea and the workaround! I'll see whether I can have Python fixed.

Comment: Issue [#105426](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/105426).